# How to find if a variable contains certain character or not ? PHP

Tags: php

**Intro**

In search, i want to make search for age range.

if a user inserts a '-' included input like *10-30* this way
 i will display list of people age greater than 10 and less than 30.

**My Question**

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars("user input from search field"));
```

From here before entering to make query i want to make two conditions, 
One: if there's a '-' in user input or not ? if yes i want to query as according, if not the other way.

So, how can i enter into the first condition ?

Comment: What's your budget? If you want us to make all the code, you don't expect it to be free, right?

Comment: [strpos()](http://us3.php.net/strpos)

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a good ROLMFHO moment @h2ooooooo

Comment: Why don't you just use a dropdown select? You know how people are generally lazy entering text, yet alone risking to make a mistake while typing. What if they entered 10--//@@!!!30 just cuz? You're giving yourself more work and trouble for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
// use strpos() because strstr() uses more resources
if(strpos("user input from search field", "-") === false)
{
    // not found provides a boolean false so you NEED the ===
}
else
{
    // found can mean "found at position 0", "found at position 19", etc...
}
```

**[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)**

**What NOT to do**

```
if(!strpos("user input from search field", "-"))
```

The example above will screw you over because `strpos()` can return a 0 (zero) which is a valid string position just as it is a valid array position.

This is why it is absolutely mandatory to check for `=== false`

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function :

```
$string= 'some string with - values ';
if(strstr($string, '-')){
    echo 'symbol is isset';
}
```

Comment: sergio, although you answer is correct using MonkeyZeus's solution is less memory intensive.

Comment: agree, it is just one of the way to resolve task